# How do I automate telegram bot to use another bot and retrieve information from it?

Tags: telegram-bot

**How do I use a public bot and retrieve information from it using my bot TELEGRAM?**

So I made a bot using BotFather, I'm going to add many functions to it, but one of them is that I want it to use another bot.

There is a bot called

> @TG_mp3downloader_bot

, which takes a youtube video URL and creates a downloadable mp3 file out of it.

How do implement or embed the @TG_mp3downloader_bot into a command in my bot?

A there a way to create a bot similar to @TG_mp3downloader_bot instead? And if so, how?

****Note: I code with python***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do implement or embed the @TG_mp3downloader_bot into a command in my bot?

You can't. [Bots can't talk to other bots.](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#why-doesn-39t-my-bot-see-messages-from-other-bots)

> there a way to create a bot similar to @TG_mp3downloader_bot instead? And if so, how?

Sure. That bot accesses information from the services mentioned in its description, so you can do that, too. Either the services have APIs that you can use, or you can use some sort of website parsing.

Comment: Thank you <3.
Oh ... I didn't realize it was in the description, maybe it's my untrained eyes unlike yours haha.